# Align search form button

Tags: html, css, forms, button, alignment

I know lots of other people have had this problem and I've combed this site and others and tried so many fixes that have helped other people and I just cannot get anything to work for me. Here is my problem:

I need to move a search button down about 2px so that it is centered with the input box. However, every time I try to adjust the padding or add a margin or anything, both the input box and the button are affected.

I have also tried adding a class just to the button part of the form, but even this is affecting the input box too.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="searchCon">    
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://somesite.com/">
<div>
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search Our Site:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">
    <input type="image" value="Search" src="button.png" id="searchsubmit" style="opacity: 1;">
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 #searchCon{
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    height:37px;
    padding: 0px 10px 10px 280px;
    color:#2a2a2a;
}
```

Any help would be incredibly appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you please post an image showing what you wish to achieve, since it's not immediately clear from your question.

Comment: BenM, unfortunately I can't post images because I don't have a good enough reputation on this site yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this in the button style:

```
<input type="image" value="Search" src="button.png" id="searchsubmit" style="opacity: 1; float: right; margin-top: 1px;">
```